# mongoose model.update not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, middleware

It used to work before. I do not know what changed...
This is the method:

User has an Array of teams. Once A Team is deleted, I wish for the RefID to be removed as well from the user's Team array

```
TeamSchema.pre('remove', function(next) {
  const team = this;
  User.update( { teams: { $in: [team._id] } }, { $pull: { teams: team._id } }, next);
});
```

getting this error:

> (node:7484) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: User.update is not a function

Also, None of the other methods work as well (`Model.findById, Model.find`, etc...), although I do have my model and mongoose imported at the top of the file.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const User = require('./user');
```

Somehow none of my `mongoose` operations work within that `Model.pre()` function.

I have another file with a `pre` method, in which the `Model.find` function works:

```
UserSchema.pre('remove', function(next) {
  const user = this;
  Team.find({ admin: { $in: [user._id] } }, function(err, teams) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    teams.forEach(function(t) {  t.remove(); });
    next
  });
});
```

Is anyone familiar with this issue?

Comment: if you require `user` from the same folder of a schema file, are you sure you are not accidentally requiring the `user schema` instead of the `user model`? Put a break point there and see if the `User.update` is a mongoose model.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `mongoose.models[modelName]`  instead of direct model name. like bellow

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
     // .....
    })

UserSchema.pre('remove', function(next) {
  const user = this;
  mongoose.models['Team'].find({ admin: { $in: [user._id] } }, function(err, teams) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    teams.forEach(function(t) {  t.remove(); });
    next();
  });
});
```

and **Team** model should exported with name `Team`. like:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Team', TeamSchema);
```